# Subscriptions does not send out "update" notifications

Tags: notifications

I am logged in as user/1 and have subscribed to a particular node. I then edited the content of the node and have ticked the "Send subscriptions notifications" option.

I did not receive an "update" notification. Why might this be the case?

By the way, I've enabled the following modules:
* Subscriptions UI
* Subscriptions Mail (+ Mail Editor + Token)
* Content Subscriptions

I am logged in as user/1 and subscribed to a number of nodes. Updating them does not send email notifications.

The settings I've got turned on are as follows:

admin/config/system/subscriptions

Unlisted content types - none

Blocked content types - none

Node form position - Fieldset above node links

Node form visibility - Always display the fieldset

Expand the node form fieldset

admin/config/system/subscriptions/userdefaults

Nodify poster of own posts Send interval - As soon as possible

On updates - ticked

Send interval - Hidden

On updates - hidden

admin/config/system/subscriptions/intervals

1|As soon as possible 900|Every 15 minutes 3600|Hourly 10800|Every three hours 86400|Daily

Do I need to enable "* Taxonomy Subscriptions (e.g. forums!)" for the subscriptions to work?

Also, not sure if this is required, but I went to admin/config/system/mail-edit and added a template fornode-type-basic_page for the Subscriptions Mail module. However, this made no difference in email updates being sent :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First you need to check your email sending capacity of your website.
- Second check that you did the correct configurations for subscriptions module.
- Finall you must run the cron (or set the timer for cron) for sending email updates for subscriptions

If you want to test at the final step, just run cron manually

Comment: From the question +1 for checking cron.

Comment: Thank you @StoneVo

I was pretty sure the site was sending out emails the other week. But I just tested the two webforms and they are NOT sending out emails. Uggggh :(

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong do I still need to worry about cron if I am just testing? I mean I am just trying to send out one email notification for one single node...

Comment: I disabled a bunch of "mail" modules which I was using for the simplenews and subscriptions modules and the webforms are being sent out yet again. I hate how fixing one things breaks the other :(

Comment: The settings I've got turned on are as follows:

admin/config/system/subscriptions

Unlisted content types - none

Blocked content types - none

Node form position - Fieldset above node links

Node form visibility - Always display the fieldset

Expand the node form fieldset

admin/config/system/subscriptions/userdefaults

Nodify poster of own posts Send interval - As soon as possible

On updates - ticked

Send interval - Hidden

On updates - hidden

admin/config/system/subscriptions/intervals

1|As soon as possible 900|Every 15 minutes 3600|Hourly 10800|Every three hours 86400|Daily

@Stone Vo

Comment: You must run cron manually to test the subscriptions. You can create a new role user for testing purpose. After you create the new role. Changes the role will receive the subscriptions in User Configuration of Subscription Module.

Comment: Thank you @Stone Vo. I have started receiving emails (user1 that is). However, I only receive one email notification a day, even though multiple updates are made... is this normal?

Comment: I just installed the subscription and mail editor modules on a new site. The emails def work because I receive the contact us form notifications. I ran the cron manually but still haven't received a subscription notification of the node being modified :(